# When is G->G/H a trivial bundle

Tags: lie-groups, principal-bundles

Suppose that $H\subseteq G$ are connected lie groups. Then $G\mapsto G/H$ is a principal $H$-bundle. I would like to know if there is some non-tautological characterization of when this is a trivial bundle.

If $H$ admits a complementary subgroup then this is certainly the case. I originally guessed that the converse was true, but this is false as shown for example by

$$G=\begin{bmatrix}1 & * & * \newline 0 & 1 & * \newline 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$

$$H=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & * \newline 0 & 1 & 0 \newline 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

(the quotient is $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is contractible, or you could just write down a section explicitly, but $G$ has no 2-dimensional abelian subgroups so there can't be a section which is also a homomorphism).

I would also be interested to know if there is a similar example where $G$ is compact.

Comment: Such a principal bundle is classified by a map $G/H\to BH$. The bundle is trivial iff the classifying map is null-homotopic. This gives a topological characterization. Not sure if it is considered tautological. I doubt that there is an easy algebraic characterization. Here is an important classic example to illustrate this: the bundle $O(n)\to O(n)/O(n-1)\cong S^{n-1}$ is trivial if only if $S^{n-1}$ is parallelizable, which is if and only if $n=1,2,4$ or $8$.

Comment: Principal bundles are trivial if and only if they admit a section. So one characterization is that you have a continuous assignment of a representative to each coset in $G/H$. Like Greg, I'm not sure if you'd consider this non-tautological.

Comment: Is it supposed to be obvious that the associated vector bundle to $O(n)\mapsto O(n)/O(n-1)$ is the tangent bundle on $S^{n-1}$?
The statement about sections was actually my original motivation for considering this question. I guess I was really wondering about a characterization in terms of algebraic or lie-theoretic data. I would happily accept an answer that claims this is not possible in sufficiently compelling terms.

Comment: There are obvious examples of compact groups $H<G$ with $G\mapsto G/H$ a trivial principal bundle, $O(8)\mapsto O(8)/O(7)$ and $O(4)\mapsto O(4)/O(3)$.

This question likely involves the Lie groups approach to characteristic classes, as in 
Borel, Hirzebruch, "Characteristic Classes and Homogeneous Spaces", Am. J. Math, 80, 1958.